# Extract last specific word/value from one column and move it to the next row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like the following

```
|Animals        | Type         | Year |
|Penguin AVES   | Omnivore     | 2015 |
|Caiman REP     | Carnivore    | 2018 |
|Komodo.Rep     | Carnivore    | 2019 |
|Blue Jay.aves  | Omnivore     | 2015 |
|Iguana+rep     | Carnivore    | 2020 |
```

I want to extract the last specific words (e.g. AVES and REP) from the values in column "Animals" and move it to the next row while keeping the values of the entire row. There are several specific words other than AVES and REP. It's not very clean (as shown by the whitespace, dot, and "+" operator before the specific words). The expected new DataFrame would be like the following

```
| Animals        | Type         | Year |
| Penguin AVES   | Omnivore     | 2015 |
| AVES           | Omnivore     | 2015 |
| Caiman REP     | Carnivore    | 2018 |
| REP            | Carnivore    | 2018 |
| Komodo.Rep     | Carnivore    | 2019 |
| Rep            | Carnivore    | 2019 |
| Blue Jay.aves  | Omnivore     | 2015 |
| aves           | Omnivore     | 2015 |
| Iguana+rep     | Carnivore    | 2020 |
| rep            | Carnivore    | 2020 |
```

I was thinking of using a negative indexing to split the string, but I got confused with the lambda function for this particular issue. Any idea how I should approach this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the last word (`(\w+)$` regex, but you can also use a specific list `(?i)(aves|rep)$` if needed) and [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) it to replace the column, then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the updated DataFrame to the original one, and [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with a stable method to interleave the rows:

```
out = (pd.concat([df, df.assign(Animals=df['Animals'].str.extract(r'(\w+)$'))])
         .sort_index(kind='stable', ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
         Animals       Type  Year
0   Penguin AVES   Omnivore  2015
1           AVES   Omnivore  2015
2     Caiman REP  Carnivore  2018
3            REP  Carnivore  2018
4     Komodo.Rep  Carnivore  2019
5            Rep  Carnivore  2019
6  Blue Jay.aves   Omnivore  2015
7           aves   Omnivore  2015
8     Iguana+rep  Carnivore  2020
9            rep  Carnivore  2020
```

###### alternative using [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
cols = df.columns.difference(['Animals']).tolist()

out = (df.assign(Word=df['Animals'].str.extract(r'(\w+)$'))
         .set_index(cols).stack().reset_index(cols, name='Animals')
         .reset_index(drop=True)[df.columns]
      )
```

###### alternative with indexing:

Duplicate all rows, modify the odd rows with the extracted word

```
out = df.loc[df.index.repeat(2)].reset_index(drop=True)

out.loc[1::2, 'Animals'] = out.loc[1::2, 'Animals'].str.extract(r'(\w+)$', expand=False)
```

Comment: I would have used `r'[\W_](\w+)$'` instead in case there is an underscore as a separator

Comment: I'd use `([a-zA-Z]+)$` in this case, anyway this part can be adapted easily by OP ;)

Comment: @mozway Thanks a lot for your help. Turns out I also have specific word in the middle (e.g. Peregrin aves Falcon) and in the front (e.g. rep Salamander). I want to solve this using regex as I find it more flexible for my dataframe, but I just started using Python and have no experience with regex. I was thinking of using like '\s' to escape the whitespace but to no avail. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question with proper example. You can restrict it to the regex part.